# Include 'count.html.php'

Tags: php, html, include

This book 'php and mysql novice to ninja' said that to include the files count.html and count.php, I must type the following into the bottom of the count.php file:

```
include 'count.html.php';
```

However, this does not seem to work unless it is just count.html without the .php.

Is this book accurate or not? I cannot find anything online about this way of including.

I've seen two separate lines of including tags such as:

```
include 'a.html';
include 'b.php';
```

Sorry for the shit formatting. I've never posted to this site before.

count.php:

```
<?php
$output = '';
for ($count = 1; $count <= 10; $count++) {
        $output .= $count . ' ';                 
}

include 'count.html.php';
?>
```

count.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>counting to ten</title>          
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <?php echo $output; ?>

        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Either rename `count.html` to `count.html.php` or use `include 'count.html';`, it would seem.

Comment: Yea, I don't believe he was clear enough with his wording. I re-read it and it looks as though he never says to directly name it as "count.html" and states that HE always names it count.html.php. It counts as a php file if you go by his method, I'm not a fan. He just makes it more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include` looks for a file name exactly matching what you put in the quotes, it will not include two different files at once as you are describing.

Your `count.html` file contains PHP code in it, so it shouldn't have the `.html` extension, it would most commonly use `.php` or since it looks mostly like an html template file, you could use `.phtml`. The extensions `.php` and `.phtml` do the exact same thing, but generally by convention if you have a file exclusively with php code, you would name it `.php`, and it it has a lot of html, you might want to name it `.phtml`. Either is fine, but not the plain `.html`.

Assuming you decided to name it `count.phtml`, then your two files would then look like:

***count.php***

```
<?php
$output = '';
for ($count = 1; $count <= 10; $count++) {
        $output .= $count . ' ';                 
}

include 'count.phtml';
?>
```

***count.phtml***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>counting to ten</title>          
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <?php echo $output; ?>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question! I figured from what the other guy said that the author was just going by his personal preference which was confusing. He was basically using the .php at the end of .html.php as a reminder to himself that it was related to the .php document. But I was unaware of this pthml!

Answer (score 0):

The author was showing his personnel method, which is confusing. Basically using the .php at the end of .html.php as a reminder to himself that it was related to the .php document. It made the html code appear as php, and the author was not the clearest.